how to update "SKU" and messaging limit of an IOThub from Azure function app (isolated)
I have a function app:
Details:

C#
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"

I was trying to retrieve the "SKU" details of an IoTHub and update it. By update I meant to increase or decrease the message quote, change the tier etc.
It appears there is a lot of limitation in sdk in the isolate side. Is there any sdk that can be used to update the iot hub properties.

The Azure.ResourceManager.IotHub package should allow you to manage the resource itself.
Note there is no limitation on isolated hosting model that would limit this.
Ultimately those are all HTTP requests which you can make from isolated model as well.

Do you have some example that can be used.

Thanks. you are correct. I am able to retrieve the description regarding the SKU. Is there an example to update it. And to retrieve the IoTHub Usage data.

Sorry, I don't have samples for that.

I also have this question, how to update the SKU？it seems the update function can only update Tags

try this:
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await GetResourceGroup();
IotHubDescriptionCollection iotHubDescriptions = resourceGroup.GetIotHubDescriptions();
IotHubDescriptionResource existingHub = await iotHubDescriptions.GetAsync(iothubname);
existingHub.Data.Sku.Capacity = newUnit;
//Update other properties you want
await iotHubDescriptions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, iothub, existingHub.Data, ifMatch: existingHub.Data.ETag.ToString());
